# replacing string number with actual number itself

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an api that calls:

http://example.com/games?maxplayers=10

then I use

```
url.parse(req.url,true).query
```

which returns:

```
{ maxplayers: '10' }
```

I would like to replace the string that contains 10 with the actual int value of 10 so I can query my database and return a result. As of right now it returns no result because it recognizes the 10 as a string. Any insight?

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
var example = parseInt(url.parse(req.url,true).query)
  console.log(example);
```

However all it prints is "NAN"

I need it to return:

```
{ maxplayers: 10 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript

Comment: This looks like JSON. You should use a JSON parser for that.

Comment: @ByteHamster: It does not look like JSON at all.`url.parse(req.url,true).query` returns an **object**. What you see is the literal representation of that object. If it was JSON, the return value would be `"{\"maxplayers\":\"10\"}"` (i.e. a string containing JSON).

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, you are right, sorry

Comment: Well `.query` is an **object**. You want to convert the value of `.query.maxplayers`. Or iterate over the properties of that object and converted them. Learn more about objects from the MDN JavaScript tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects